# FormatException and ArgumentException errors

Tags: visual-studio, asp.net-core, argumentexception, formatexception

I get these errors in `Visual Studio` in an `ASP.NET Core 2.1` application while attempting to change identity from string to long. Has anyone else run into these errors?

> An unhandled exception occurred while processing the request.
>   FormatException: Input string was not in a correct format.
>   System.Number.StringToNumber(ReadOnlySpan str, NumberStyles
>   options, ref NumberBuffer number, NumberFormatInfo info, bool
>   parseDecimal) ArgumentException: 81d1aa6c-b70a-4d64-a62a-e177d79b944e
>   is not a valid value for Int64. Parameter name: value
>   System.ComponentModel.BaseNumberConverter.ConvertFrom(ITypeDescriptorContext
>   context, CultureInfo culture, object value)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overlow. What value is in the string that you are trying to convert? Can you add the code that is doing the convert (and causing the exception to be thrown) into your question please.

Comment: There's really not enough here to actually help you. However, my best guess is that you have existing users in your database and you didn't bother to migrate after making the change from string to long. As a result, it's now trying to parse the old string ids into longs, and of course, failing.

Comment: I restarted visual studio (2017) and proceeded as follows: drop database after deleting files in migrations folder, add migration, update database. Now the following error creeps up for an asp.net core 2.1 project: An unhandled exception occurred while processing the request.
InvalidOperationException: No service for type 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.UserManager`1[Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.IdentityUser]' has been registered.
Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProviderServiceExtensions.GetRequiredService(IServiceProvider provider, Type serviceType)

Answer (score 0):

For changing Identity primary key from `string` to `long`, follow steps below:

- Add `ApplicationUser.cs`

  ```
  public class ApplicationUser:IdentityUser<long>
  {
  }
  ```
- Modify `ApplicationDbContext`

  ```
  public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser, IdentityRole<long>, long>
  {
      public ApplicationDbContext(DbContextOptions<ApplicationDbContext> options)
          : base(options)
      {
      }
  }
  ```
- Modify `Startup.cs`

  ```
          services.AddDefaultIdentity<ApplicationUser>()
              .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>();
  ```
- Modify `_LoginPartial.cshtml` from `IdentityUser` to `ApplicationUser`

  ```
             @using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity

  @inject SignInManager<ApplicationUser> SignInManager
  @inject UserManager<ApplicationUser> UserManager

  @if (SignInManager.IsSignedIn(User))
  {
      <form asp-area="Identity" asp-page="/Account/Logout" asp-route-returnUrl="@Url.Action("Index", "Home", new { area = "" })" method="post" id="logoutForm" class="navbar-right">
          <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
              <li>
                  <a asp-area="Identity" asp-page="/Account/Manage/Index" title="Manage">Hello @UserManager.GetUserName(User)!</a>
              </li>
              <li>
                  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-link navbar-btn navbar-link">Logout</button>
              </li>
          </ul>
      </form>
  }
  else
  {
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
          <li><a asp-area="Identity" asp-page="/Account/Register">Register</a></li>
          <li><a asp-area="Identity" asp-page="/Account/Login">Login</a></li>
      </ul>
  }
  ```